# Can i decide to have x null rows on a left join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

There is my issue :

I have two tables that i want to left join, and i want to display X rows depending on how many records there are in the second table.

Example :

```
TABLE_A                                               TABLE_B
---------------------                            -----------------------------------
| idA       | yearA |                            |   idB  | idRefA   | integ | lab  |
|-------------------|                            |--------------------------------  |
|   1      |   2010 |                            |   20   |    2     |   54  |   x  |
|   2      |   2011 |                            |   20   |    2     |   50  |   y  |
|   3      |   2012 |                            |   20   |    2     |   28  |   z  |
|   4      |   2013 |                            |   21   |    3     |   18  |   x  |
|   5      |   2014 |                            |   21   |    3     |   22  |   y  |
---------------------                            |   21   |    3     |   32  |   z  |
                                                 ------------------------------------
```

There are my two tables.

This is my SQL query to join them :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.ida = TABLE_B.idrefa
```

But i haven't the result that i expect, here is the result :

| idA | yearA | idB | idRefA | integ | lab |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | null | null | null | null |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 28 | z |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 50 | y |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 54 | x |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 32 | z |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 22 | y |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 18 | x |
| 4 | 2013 | null | null | null | null |
| 5 | 2014 | null | null | null | null |

I am trying to have X rows on my `LEFT JOIN` (here X = 3). To complete the missing rows. Something like :

```
1 2010 19 1 0 x 
1 2010 19 1 0 y
1 2010 19 1 0 z 
      ...
```

Is it possible to do with a SELECT and LEFT JOIN ?

Here is my desired result :

| ida | yearA | idb | idrefa | integ | lab |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | 2010 | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | 2010 | null | null | null | null |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 28 | z |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 50 | y |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 54 | x |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 32 | z |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 22 | y |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 18 | x |

Thanks for answer

Comment: the results you show are exactly what you would expect from a left join, naturally. I don't understand your desired results, show your actual desired results.

Comment: Hi @Stu , i have edited my post if it can help you. Maybe i haven't to do a LEFT JOIN, it was for the example.

Comment: UNION ALL a SELECT that returns the 3 null rows.

Comment: How do i have to use it ? Because i haven't the same number of rows & cols in the two tables ?

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: Hi @KaziMohammadAliNur , i'm using MySQL

Comment: Which version? is it mysql 8?

Comment: No it's not, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schemar and insert statements:

```
 create table TABLE_A(idA  int, yearA int);
 insert into TABLE_A values(   1      ,   2010 );
 insert into TABLE_A values(   2      ,   2011 );
 insert into TABLE_A values(   3      ,   2012 );
 insert into TABLE_A values(   4      ,   2013 );
 insert into TABLE_A values(   5      ,   2014 );

 create table TABLE_B( idB int,   idRefA int,    integ int,  lab varchar(10)  );

 insert into TABLE_B values(   20  ,    2     ,   54  ,   'x'  );
 insert into TABLE_B values(   20  ,    2     ,   50  ,   'y'  );
 insert into TABLE_B values(   20  ,    2     ,   28  ,   'z'  );
 insert into TABLE_B values(   21  ,    3     ,   18  ,   'x'  );
 insert into TABLE_B values(   21  ,    3     ,   22  ,   'y'  );
 insert into TABLE_B values(   21  ,    3     ,   32  ,   'z'  );
```

Query#1 (for MySQL version older than 8.0):

```
 SELECT min(ida)over() ida,min(yeara)over()yearA,idb,idrefa,integ,lab FROM TABLE_A 
 LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.ida = TABLE_B.idrefa
 where TABLE_B.idrefa is null
 union all
 SELECT * FROM TABLE_A 
 LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.ida = TABLE_B.idrefa
 where TABLE_B.idrefa is not null
```

Output:

| ida | yearA | idb | idrefa | integ | lab |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | 2010 | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | 2010 | null | null | null | null |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 54 | x |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 50 | y |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 28 | z |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 18 | x |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 22 | y |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 32 | z |

Query#2 (for MySQL version 8.0 and above):

```
 SELECT (case when idrefa is null then min(ida)over(partition by idrefa) else ida end)ida,(case when idrefa is null then min(yeara)over(partition by idrefa) else yearA end)yearA,idb,idrefa,integ,lab FROM TABLE_A 
 LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.ida = TABLE_B.idrefa
 order by yearA
```

Output:

| ida | yearA | idb | idrefa | integ | lab |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | 2010 | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | 2010 | null | null | null | null |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 28 | z |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 50 | y |
| 2 | 2011 | 20 | 2 | 54 | x |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 32 | z |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 22 | y |
| 3 | 2012 | 21 | 3 | 18 | x |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56cca91d95a8d856ff1f634abf438390)*

Comment: Yes this is it. Thanks for your answer it will help me

Comment: You are most welcome. I have included answer for MySQL 8.0 too.